# How to print label for a value in c++

Tags: c++, console, printf

I have print function in c++ which prints out the speed and other things as well. The function output speed:325 but I am trying to add MPH with value of speed for example 320 mph but i am not shore how to do this. packet.speed function receives data from the the client. Here is the below function I have used.

```
printf("Flight Number %d: speed %d: longitude %.f, latitude %.f\n",
       packet.clientID,
       packet.speed,
       packet.longitude,
       packet.latitude);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1** Simply add "MPH" to the format string.

```
printf("Flight Number %d: speed %d MPH: longitude %.f, latitude %.f\n",
       packet.clientID,
       packet.speed,
       packet.longitude,
       packet.latitude);
```

**Option 2** Add "MPH" as another argument to `printf`.

```
printf("Flight Number %d: speed %d %s: longitude %.f, latitude %.f\n",
       packet.clientID,
       packet.speed,
       "MPH"
       packet.longitude,
       packet.latitude);
```